# Preview formatting doesn't match real formatting when italics are within quotation marks

Tags: bug, markdown-rendering, markdown-preview

I am currently editing a post. The first line is

```
i have two tables "*TABLE_A*" and "*TABLE_B*",
```

The italics work in the preview, but not in the rendered post. In the rendered post, I can see the actual asterisks.

> i have two tables "*TABLE_A*" and "*TABLE_B*",

---

Hmm. Here it works the same way in both preview and rendered post. Possibly this is a bug which has already been fixed, and the post I'm looking at is old enough to have saved HTML which predates the fix.